# foreach in table format using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<tbody>
        <?php foreach($result as $row){ ?>
        <?php foreach($result1 as $row1) {?>
            <tr>

            <td >
                <span><?php echo $row->state; ?></span>
            </td>
            <td >
                <span><?php echo $row->breakdown_grants; ?></span>
            </td>

            <td >
                <span><?php echo $row1->breakdown_grants; ?></span>
            </td>

            </tr>
            <?php } ?>  

            <?php } ?>  
        </tbody>
```

I need to display my coding in table format.in that first foreach contain state and breakdown_grants value.

```
state           actual                     provisional

$row->state    $row->breakdown_grants     $row1->breakdown_grants
```

this is my table format.what i need to change in my foreach.in $result and $result1 i'll get different data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you use for loop like

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span><?php echo $result[$i]->state; ?></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span><?php echo $result[$i]->breakdown_grants; ?></span>
        </td>

        <td>
            <span><?php echo $result1[$i]->breakdown_grants; ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

Make sure that $result and $result1 are of same indexes and of same lengths.

Comment: extremely thanks alot gautam.what i need i got it.

Comment: Glad it helps for you @sangee..